# Linux Ubuntu Files behind the mount

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, nfs, ext4

```
root@host:~# mkdir -p /tmp/test
root@host:~# echo "test" >> /tmp/test/file.txt
root@host:~# mount /dev/xy /tmp/test/
```

How can I now access file.txt without unmount /dev/xy?

Comment: Write a filesystem driver that can handle your broken use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to see it by using a bind mount e.g.

```
mount --bind /tmp /mnt
```

then

```
cat /mnt/test/file.txt
test
```

You have to bind mount the filesystem that contains the original file. In this case /tmp. This may not work with some filesystems e.g. zfs.